# The Mac App Store won't let me update iMovie and iPhoto because it says i bought them under a different account

Tags: macbook-pro, mac-appstore, software-update

I just bought this computer in August -- i have been the only one to use it, have only used it under my itunes/apple account. But ever since the first week or so that i've had it, i've had update available for iMovie and iPhoto that it won't let me use because it says i'm not signed into the account i bought them with.

Any fix to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Contact [Apple billing support](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3552) and/or the place you purchased the Mac to see if they can assist with resolving the server side issue. The OS updates are tied to the serial number, but the iLife apps go through a redeem process where the hardware identifier and your Apple ID get bond together, and the Apple servers apparently think a different account is set up for those apps on your Mac.

I'm assuming you have no idea and don't recognize the other Apple ID and it wasn't just a case of you accidentally redeeming the applications. I'm also assuming you can sign into the account you intended to redeem these apps. At worst, Apple or the seller should be able to gift you the apps to the correct account so you can get updates going forward if you (or someone else trying to be helpful) has made a mistake.

Here is what a Mac should look like before you have "accepted" the iLife apps by opening the App Store App and signing in and choosing Purchases (command-4) from the menu bar.

[image: Accept iLife purchases]

Answer (score 1):

I remember a similar problem for users whose Mac were running languages different than American English.

For those it could be fixed by setting the system language to american english - reboot - do the updates - then set language back to their preferences and reboot again.

I know it sounds rather like black magic and unfortunately I can't locate the reference. But might be worth a try.